# How does Microsoft Windows SDK relate to .net Framework

Tags: .net, sdk, msbuild, build-server

**Question:** I am just totally confused about those two things when it comes to building .net Applications.

How do those two relate?

Why is MSBuild located in .net Framework folder (C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319) and not in the SDK?

Do I always need the corresponding SDK Version for "it's" .net Framework version  (i.e.: SDK 7.1 for .net 4.0) or can I use a newer SDK for an older .net Framework?

**Background:**
I have to reinstall a Build Server (Jenkins) and I need to build a range of .net Applications with many different Framework version (2.0, 3.5, 4.0, 4.5, ...) and I want to install only what I really need.